# Prepend header in seperate document to page

Tags: jquery, html

I have a header pre-made in a separate file on my server and I want to prepend it to certain documents on my website. 
What would be the easiest way to do this?
personally I'd think of using the jQuery .prepend() function, but I can't quite get around to getting the header file loaded.

Comment: Use a server-side include. JavaScript should be the last thing you use for includes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Jquery you can do this :

```
$(function(){
    $.get("http://domainname.com/path/header.php",function(res){
       $("#divId-to-prepend").prepend(res);
    });
});
```

Try this.

Answer (score 1):

Do it in php. Use include function to do it:

```
<?php include "header.php"; ?>
```

Comment: I'd do that, but my server is an old PC running Windows Server 2003, so setting PHP up in the first place would be a pain in the ass.

Comment: I've used the jQuery solution for now, but I'd be happy if you could give me a solution which is easier to set up than PHP